# Joomla Helix3 Custom Javascript Whitepage

Tags: joomla

I have a Joomla site which I just bricked by inserting some javascript into the [custom code] -> [custom javascript] area of the Helix3 template.

I am just wondering where to find where the code is saved so that I can delete it.

Answer (score 0):

The custom Javascript code in the Helix Ultimate template is stored in the [prefix]_template_styles table in the Joomla database along with other template settings.

I recommend running a backup before making any changes as it's not especially easy to identify the exact code to delete.